# OPC UA python access client.get_node with variable

Tags: python, automation, opc-ua, opc

I have to write python client to access with a variables to a node in opc ua from a client. I mean something like:

```
reg_conf=150 #it's an example, but I read this value from user input
client.get_node("ns=1;i=reg_conf")
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
node = client.get_node("ns=1;i=reg_conf")
reg_conf = node.get_value()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your aim is to inject the value of `reg_conf` (which is a user input) into your node id.

There are several ways to achieve that in Python. Here are two of them:

1. String concatenation: Type-cast the value of `reg_conf` to `str` and concatenate with the remaining node id.

```
reg_conf = 150
node_id = "ns=1;i="+str(reg_conf)
node = client.get_node(node_id)

# Get value of this node
node_value = node.get_value()
```

2. String injection: Use `format()` method of the string object to insert the value of `reg_conf`

```
reg_conf = 150 
node = client.get_node("ns=1;i={x}".format(x=reg_conf))

# Get value of this node
node_value = node.get_value()
```